# Debug log file location in Visual Studio run .NET applicaiton

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

When I run my `.Net` application in `Visual Studio` there is a debug log in the Output section:

[image]

Is this written to some file or how could it be parsed?

Comment: Have a look at this blogpost: https://blog.bytellect.com/software-development/dot-net-framework/how-do-i-control-where-debug-writeline-debug-output-goes-in-csharp/

Comment: ^^ TL;DR: `TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener("myDebugLogFile.txt")); Debug.Listeners.Add(myListener);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
TextWriterTraceListener myListener = new TextWriterTraceListener("myDebugLogFile.txt")); Debug.Listeners.Add(myListener);
```